# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save1'

Tags: python, typeerror

```
nice = 2

class saving(object):
    def __init__(self,save1, save2, save3, save4, save5, save6, save7, save8, save9, save10):
        self.save1 = save1
        self.save2 = save2
        self.save3 = save3
        self.save4 = save4
        self.save5 = save5
        self.save6 = save6
        self.save7 = save7
        self.save8 = save8
        self.save9 = save9
        self.save10 = save10
        self.writesaves = open('Saves.txt', 'w')
    def save(self):
        data1 = self.save1
        print(data1)


test = saving(nice, 'xp', 'gems', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.')
saving.save(1)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 'file', line 22, in <module>
    saving.save(1)
  File "file", line 17, in save
    data1 = self.save1
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save1'
```

Comment: could you please reformat your code so that we can read it?  And maybe cut it down to a minimum code required to illustrate the problem?

Comment: how can i make it so that it doesn't remove my enters?

Comment: Should be `test.save(1)`

Comment: `test.save()`... `save` takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
test = saving(nice, 'xp', 'gems', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.')
saving.save(1)
```

Where `saving` is your class and `test` is an instance of that class.

When you call:

```
saving.save(1)
```

You are invoking the `save` method in the `saving` class and passing it `1`. So, instead of `self` referring to an object, it just contains the integer `1`, which is why `self.save1` causes the `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save1'`

Your fix is that you should be calling `test.save()` instead, to call the `save` method for the `test` object.

As an aside, instead of referring to 10 separate `savex` objects, you would be much better off using a data structure such as a list of 10 values and accessing them via an index.

As a second aside, having a class, method and variables called saving, save and save*x* might be a source of some confusion.